# Typing a "complex" object with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object

I'm trying to see if I can get VS Code to assist me when typing an object with predefined types.

A dish object can look like this:

```json
{
      "id": "dish01",
      "title": "SALMON CRUNCH",
      "price": 120,
      "ingredients": [
        "MARINERAD LAX",
        "PICKLADE GRÖNSAKER",
        "KRISPIG VITLÖK",
        "JORDÄRTSKOCKSCHIPS",
        "CHILIMAJONNÄS"
      ],
      "options": [
        {
          "option": "BAS",
          "choices": ["RIS", "GRÖNKÅL", "MIX"],
          "defaultOption": "MIX"
        }
      ]
}
```

My current attempt looks like this

```
enum DishOptionBaseChoices {
  Rice = 'RIS',
  Kale = 'GRÖNKÅL',
  Mix = 'MIX',
}

type DishOption<T> = {
  option: string
  choices: T[]
  defaultOption: T
}

type DishOptions = {
  options: DishOption<DishOptionBaseChoices>[]
}

type Dish = {
  id: string
  title: string
  price: number
  ingredients: string[]
  options: DishOptions
}
```

(not sure if some of them should be `interface` instead of `type`)

the plan is to make enums for all "types" of options. The auto-suggestion works fine with the `id` but not when writing the `options`.

[image: vscode example]

### Working solution

```
type ChoiceForBase = 'RIS' | 'GRÖNKÅL' | 'MIX'

type DishOption<OptionType, ChoiceType> = {
  option: OptionType
  choices: ChoiceType[]
  defaultOption: ChoiceType
}

type Dish = {
  id: string
  title: string
  price: number
  ingredients: string[]
  options: DishOption<'BAS', ChoiceForBase>[]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On type `Dish` you defined `options: DishOptions`, but then on type `DishOptions` you again defined a property `options`. So with you current types definition your options property looks like this:

```
const dish: Dish = {
    options: {
        options: [{
            choices: ...
        }]
    }
}
```

If you want `options` to be an array of `DishOption` change your `Dish` definition:

```
type Dish = {
    id: string
    title: string
    price: number
    ingredients: string[]
    options: DishOption<DishOptionBaseChoices>[]
}
```

Comment: Good catch! It now suggest the keys. Shouldn't it also suggest the string for `defaultOption` when typing?

Comment: Arhh.. I just have to use a type with `|` instead of enum

Comment: `DishOptionBaseChoices` is enum, that's not the same as string. It will suggest you the enum values if you try typing this: `defaultOption: DishOptionBaseChoices.` If you really want `defaultOption` to be just a string you can define your type like this: `type DishOptionBaseChoices = 'RIS' | 'GRÖNKÅL' | 'MIX'`